# Replacing accented letters with regular letters in a spreadsheet

Tags: performance, vba

I am using the following VBA code to replace accented letters with regular letters in a spreadsheet. This is necessary because these spreadsheets have to be uploaded to an import tool that does not allow foreign characters.

```
Function RemoveAccentsFromForeignLetters()

    StartNewTask ("Removing accents from foreign letters")

    Dim AccChars As String
    Dim RegChars As String

    AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
    RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Dim A As String * 1
    Dim B As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        MyRange.Replace What:=A, Replacement:=B, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
        ' TODO: highlight changed cells yellow
    Next

End Function
```

I googled the code from somewhere and it works, but it is a bit slow. In a spreadsheet with 1.5 million cells (7000 rows, 200 columns), it takes 21 seconds to run.

I wanted to look into ways to optimize it, for example:

- Maybe a RegEx would be faster?
- Maybe I should pass the entire spreadsheet to a DLL using an array, have the DLL do the replace, then pass it back? One article I read suggested that this is up to 10x faster than using native Excel VBA.
- Maybe I should use the same DLL trick as above, but add multi-threading?
- Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Raystafarian's observations, there are a couple of other issues that I see.

1. I would personally put your `AccChars` and `RegChars` variables into
   `Const`s, because you never change their values.
2. Your code also requires that `AccChars` and `RegChars` are the same
   length, and will fail if they aren't.  I'd add an assert that tests
   that before you do anything that writes to the Worksheet.
3. You generally want to avoid using the `Integer` type unless you
   absolutely need to (for example in an API call). VBA stores them as a
   `Long` regardless of how they are declared.
4. Declaring `A` and `B` as fixed-length strings is a bit of premature
   optimization that is backfiring. When you pass them to `.Replace` as
   parameters, they are actually being implicitly cast *back* to
   variable length ones.
5. Minor thing, but I prefer the term "stripped" to "regular" - *all*
   characters are "regular" in their native context.
6. Using string functions is not ideal when what you really care about
   are individual characters as opposed to a sub-string.  VBA allows a
   direct assignment of a `String` to a `Byte` array, and indexing into
   the array is much faster than calling `Mid`. The performance hit is a
   lot higher when you're doing it inside a loop. As a side note, you
   should always use the `String` returning functions that end with '$'
   to avoid superfluous casting unless you explicitly require a
   `Variant` type. `Mid$` (returns a `String`) as opposed to `Mid`
   (returns a `Variant`).
7. Your call to `.Replace` method is acting on every single cell in your
   `Range`. This is a huge performance hit, because I'm guessing that
   not every cell in the entire Worksheet is going to have an accented
   character in it. You should really only be concerned with cells that
   *do*. By performing the replacement on every cell, your performance is scaling directly with the number of cells, *not* the number of
   replacements. So, if only 5% of the cells have accented characters
   you are still doing 100% of the work. This is where the regular
   expression would be useful, but you can't easily pawn that off on
   Excel (except maybe with using `.Find`, which has issues of its own).
   A loop would be better - a loop over an array pulled from the `Range`
   would be best.
8. Your "TODO: highlight changed cells yellow" is going to be much more
   difficult using the `.Replace` function, because it would require
   storing the state of the entire sheet, then doing a cell-by-cell
   comparison. It will be a lot easier to track this concurrently while
   you are making changes.

With all of that in mind, I'd do something more like this:

```
Private Sub RemoveAccentsFromForeignLetters()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    StartNewTask ("Removing accents from foreign letters")

    Dim Values() As Variant
    Values = Target.Value

    Debug.Assert Len(AccentedChars) = Len(StrippedChars)

    Dim FindChars() As Byte
    Dim ReplaceChars() As Byte
    FindChars = AccentedChars
    ReplaceChars = StrippedChars

    Dim AccentedTest As RegExp
    Set AccentedTest = New RegExp
    AccentedTest.Pattern = "[" & AccentedChars & "]"

    Dim index As Long
    Dim character As Long

    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 1 To UBound(Values, 1)
        For col = 1 To UBound(Values, 2)
            'Ignore strings that don't require character replacements.
            If AccentedTest.Test(Values(row, col)) Then
                Dim buffer() As Byte
                buffer = StrConv(Values(row, col), vbUnicode)
                'Skip every other character - VBA "Unicode" expansion 
                'inserts nulls there.
                For character = 0 To UBound(buffer) Step 2
                    For index = 0 To UBound(FindChars)
                        If buffer(character) = FindChars(index) Then
                            buffer(character) = ReplaceChars(index)
                        End If
                    Next index
                Next character
                'Highlight changed cells yellow left as an exercise for
                'the reader.
                Values(row, col) = StrConv(buffer, vbFromUnicode)
            End If
        Next col
    Next row

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange = Values
End Sub
```

Some quick and dirty benchmarks, all done with 2000 rows and 10 columns.  In the "worse case" benchmarks, all cells have the value "ŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎ".  In the "average case" benchmarks, 5% of the cells have the "ŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎ" and the rest of them contain "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

```
Replace method, worst case: 3.51 seconds. 
Array method, worst case: 1.15 seconds. 
Replace method, average case: .40 seconds (supports disabling ScreenUpdating). 
Array method, average case: .08 seconds.
```

Comment: WOW. Execution time on my benchmark file with 1.5 million cells went from 20.62 seconds to 1.61 seconds. Much faster code! And you're saying that, for some reason, MyRange.Replace changes every cell in the workbook? So your idea of converting the sheet to a Range variable, making the changes to the variable, then writing the variable back to the sheet is much faster? Looking forward to your response. I want to wrap my head around this so that I can optimize other functions :-)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama - Writing values to cells is a deceptively expensive procedure - think about everything Excel has to do.  It has to check for formula references to the updated cell, if it finds any it has to update those cells, it has to properly format the value, test for conditional expressions, redraw the screen, etc.  You can actually *watch* it if you have ScreenUpdating active. You'll see it repeatedly writing the cell values back and then redrawing.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama - I should clarify.  MyRange.Replace *operates on* every cell in MyRange. It only *changes* cells that have text that is replaced.

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware of #6. Nice

Comment: Yes. Doing **anything** to a spreadsheet incurs enormous computational overhead. Every single time. Setting one Range and writing to an array and then writing back at the end is only 2 spreadsheet operations. Hence why it is \*so\* much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this is a function rather than a sub - you're *doing* something, not *returning* something.

I don't see you dimensioning `myRange`. When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> **Performance**. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding
>   (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

By not declaring variables, you could possibly be paying a penalty.

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

Another good way to speed up your macro is to use `Application.Screenupdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Just be sure to return them to `True` and `xlAutomatic` and `True` before exiting the sub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) I chose function so that I would not clutter the macros list. Every sub shows up in the macros list. Should I use Private Sub instead of Function? 2) What modifications should I make to the myRange code to get around the dimensioning/performance issue you mentioned? 3) I tried turning off ScreenUpdating, Calculation, and EnableEvents and the code still took the exact same amount of time (20.79 seconds) to execute on my test document.

Comment: Yeah you could make it private. You just need to `dim myRange as __`