# Converting all cells to text

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

Microsoft Excel cells basically have two values: the formatted value that is shown to the user, and the actual value of the cell. These two values can be extremely different when the cell has certain formatting types such as date, datetime, currency, numbers with commas, etc.

I am writing a script that cleans up database data. It uses find, replace, RegEx, and other functions that act on strings of text. I need to be able to convert data into very specific formats so that my upload tool will accept the data. Therefore I need all of the cells in my Excel spreadsheets to be TEXT. I need the displayed values to match the actual values.

This is surprisingly hard to do in Excel. There is no paste special option that I could find that pastes what you see on your screen as text. "Paste Special -> Values" pastes, predictably, unformatted values. So if you try to "Paste Special -> Values" into cells formatted as TEXT, and they are coming from cells formatted as DATES, you might get something like this:

Old Cell: 4/7/2001

New Cell: 36988

If you paste normally, then the paste goes in as 4/7/2001, but in date format. So if I create a RegEx that looks for 4/7/2001 and changes it to 4/7/01, it will not work, because the underlying value is 36988.

Anyway, I discovered the `Cell.Text` property and wrote some code that converts all cells in a spreadsheet from formatted to text. But the code has two major problems:

1) It does not work on cells with more than 255 characters. This is because `Cell.Text` literally displays what the cell is actually showing to the user, and if the column is too narrow, it will display pound signs (`########`), and columns have a maximum width of 255 characters.

2) It is extremely slow. In my 1.5 million cell test sheet, code execution took 394 seconds.

I'm looking for ideas to optimize the code's speed, and to make the code work on all display value lengths.

```
Function ConvertAllCellsToText()

    ' Convert all cells from non-text to text
    ' This is helpful in a variety of ways
        ' Dates and datetimes can now be manipulated by replace, RegEx, etc., since their value is now 4/7/2001 instead of 36988
        ' Phone numbers and zip codes won't get leading zeros deleted if we try to add those

    StartNewTask "Converting all cells to text"

    ' first draft of the code, does not work as intended, dates get scrambled
    'Cells.Select
    'Selection.Copy
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ' prevent Cell.Text from being ########
    MyRange.ColumnWidth = 255

    Dim i As Long
    Dim CellText As String
    For Each Cell In MyRange
        If Cell.Text <> Cell.Value And Len(Cell.Value) <= 255 Then
            CellText = Cell.Text
            Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            Cell.Value = CellText
        End If

        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 2500 = 0 Then
            RefreshScreen
        End If
    Next

    MyRange.ColumnWidth = 20

    ' set all cells to Text format
    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

End Function
```

Comment: Do you control the code that produces the excel sheet in the first place?

Comment: @Taemyr No. The incoming data is either exported from various online registration websites, or it is a spreadsheet created by a human. My script formats it so that an upload tool can then upload it into our website. Our upload tool is strict, and one error will abort the upload process. Also, the tool is not verbose, and often won't pinpoint the cause of the error. Finally, the tool uses a queue, so if the import fails you will not know for a while. That is why I decided to tackle the problem in Excel. If the data is high enough quality, it will import smoothly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code has basically the same performance issue as your [last question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/123820/36565), and the performance solution is pretty much the same.  Other things to note:

1. This is more of a nag than anything, but you should really remove
   dead code that is commented out.
2. The variable `Cell` is never declared. You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your code modules. See [Why should I
   dimension my variables in VBA
   really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30785133/4088852) over on SO.
3. You don't return a value, so this should really be a `Sub`, not a
   `Function`.  If you don't want it to appear in the macro list,
   declare it as `Private`. I'd get into the habit of *always*
   explicitly declaring your scope.
4. **You have a bug.**  You explain pretty clearly in your question that
   the `.Value` of a cell can differ dramatically from the `.Text` of a
   cell depending on the formatting. However, when you test the length
   of the cell values, you're checking against the *Value* that you
   already point out is not dependant on the formatting.  You need to
   test the *Text* against your width.
5. **You have another possible bug** (not addressed in the code below) -
   for proportional width fonts, the value referred to by `ColumnWidth`
   is based on the width of the character '0' ([see the
   documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837430.aspx)).
   If you happen to be using a font where *any character* is wider than
   '0' (for example 'X' in my browser's default font), you can't reliably use the `ColumnWidth` as a proxy for the
   length of a string that it can display.
6. 255 is the magic number, yes it is. Since you're testing the maximum
   width of a text rendered cell to this value, and using it in
   multiple places in your code to provide formatting information, make
   it a constant and give it an appropriate name.
7. I'm assuming that the call to `RefreshScreen` is to provide some
   sort of indication to the user that something is actually happening
   instead of a hung script.  I'd remove it completely.  If you call
   `DoEvents` Excel will have a chance to update the screen buffer. 
   This is not only more performant (it avoids a function call), but it
   will also be clearer to the reader what is going on. Even better
   would be to simply omit it, as redrawing the screen is what is
   killing your in performance in the first place (see below).
8. Personally, I would cache the column widths and reset them when you
   are done instead of using the arbitrary value '20'.  This upholds
   the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).
9. You set the `NumberFormat` to text for the entire Worksheet at the
   end of the `Function`.  Setting it for individual cells inside your
   loop is not only redundant, but forces a `ScreenUpdate`. This is
   *killing* your performance. Basically, what is happening is that you are updating the display *once for every cell* in the `UsedRange`.
   This is incredibly expensive.  Turn `ScreenUpdating` off instead.
10. As I mentioned in comments to your previous question, updating cells
    is more expensive in terms of performance than you might guess. 
    When you are working with large ranges of cells, you should pull
    them into an array if at all possible, then write the *entire array*
    back at once. This lowers your "Excel overhead" almost
    quadratically.
11. You should avoid using the `Cells` collection (it is entirely
    dependant on what object is active) and the `Selection` object
    (almost every operation can be performed with the `Range` you
    already have a reference to).
12. Use `With` blocks to your advantage, especially in loops.  Every
     '.' operator that you see in your code causes an object deference
     call.  Wrapping sections where the same object is used repeatedly
     in a `With` block essentially caches the result of the deference
     instead of repeatedly performing it.
13. Similar note with pulling cell values from a `Range`.  Accessing
     the object is much more expensive than storing it.  If you have to
     reference the same value twice (looking at you, `If Cell.Text <> Cell.Value And Len(Cell.Value) <= 255 Then`), cache it.

The above notes basically boil down to something more like this:

```
Const MaxTextLength = 255

Private Sub ConvertAllCellsToText()
    StartNewTask "Converting all cells to text"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim cache() As Long
    cache = GetColumnWidths(MyRange)

    With MyRange
        .ColumnWidth = MaxTextLength
        Dim Values() As Variant
        ReDim Values(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)

        Dim col As Long
        Dim row As Long

        For row = 0 To UBound(Values, 1)
            For col = 0 To UBound(Values, 2)
                Dim temp As String
                temp = .Cells(row + 1, col + 1).Text
                If Len(temp) <= MaxTextLength Then
                    Values(row, col) = temp
                End If
            Next col
        Next row
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

    MyRange = Values
    SetColumnWidths MyRange, cache
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnWidths(Target As Range) As Long()
    Dim output() As Long
    ReDim output(1 To Target.Columns.Count)
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
        output(index) = Target.Columns(index).ColumnWidth
    Next index
    GetColumnWidths = output
End Function

Private Sub SetColumnWidths(Target As Range, widths() As Long)
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(widths) To UBound(widths)
        Target.Columns(index).ColumnWidth = widths(index)
    Next index
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** I didn't benchmark this, but I'd ballpark about 100 times faster.

**EDIT:** Almost forgot.  If you have a bunch of numbers in your sheet, you'll want to [ignore the numbers stored as text errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36167136/4088852) to get another nominal performance gain.  Call it before you turn `ScreenUpdating` back on.

Comment: Thanks for the code review and the working code! 1) I benchmarked it and it is 3 times faster. Task execution time is down to 126 seconds now. 2) The reason I use RefreshScreen is to call DoEvents so the program doesn't look hung, and also to update a timer label I have on my UserForm. VBA doesn't let the timer run separately like in Visual Basic. 3) This function still doesn't work for values greater than 255 characters. Any ideas? Perhaps finding the Excel function that converts values to text? Text = Function(Value, Formatting)? Then build an array? Thanks again.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama - The underlying issue is that Excel won't let you size a column wider than 255 characters.  You could try `.WrapText = True`. Just out of curiosity, was your benchmark with or without the `RefreshScreen` call?

Comment: 1) The benchmark was without the RefreshScreen call. 2) I did some experimentation and discovered that the column width only messes up Cell.Text if it is a date, because of the ###### thing. Running Cell.Text on a cell formatted General with lots of text in it will return all the text, even if all of it isn't visible to the user. So the 255 trick solves the error, since a date will never be wider than 255.

Answer (score 2):

@Comintern's answer has already covered your current approach quite comprehensively, so I won't add anything there. Instead, I'm going to critique your approach itself.

Speaking as somebody who's entire job is to (ab)use Excel in ways it was not really meant to be used, please take this to heart:

---

### **Excel is not a database**

However, since you don't have a choice in the matter, here's some advice for you:

---

### Always keep an original copy of the data

Right now, you are taking your data and re-formatting it. If you screw up the formatting, do you have a reliable way to recover the original data? I generally designate one sheet as the "Source" sheet, then any further work always starts with making a copy of that data.

---

### Use DataTypes to your advantage

You have no control over the data you receive. There are an effectively infinite number of formats it could be in. Right now, as soon as some data appears in a format your regex hasn't accounted for, you're screwed.

So, assume nothing, and leverage the power of VBA's Data Type recognition. Take dates for example. You mention DateValues (E.G. `36988`) as a problem. It's the exact opposite. Rather than work around them, work with them.

Pass your sheet values into an Array (has the added advantage that you can now ignore text and column widths and all that mess). Now all your dates are in a consistent, known format (a DateValue). Then, convert them all to a specific string format using the `Format()` function E.G.

`If IsDate(value) then values(x, y) = Format(value, "dd/mm/yy")`

Et voila, now you don't care what format your dates are in when you receive them, because Excel will do the hard work of converting them to a DateValue for you, and you can convert them to a specific output format with a single line.

Don't try to second guess your data. Hundreds of thousands of Developer-Hours went into giving Excel the ability to do the hard work for you. So, let it figure out what kind of data you're receiving, take those values, define formats for the handful of different Data Types and never worry about your source formatting again.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I upvoted your answer and mulled this over for a few days. In the end, I decided I am going to stick with the "convert all to text" strategy, and add any "weird" dates to my RegEx on a case-by-case basis. My reason for this is 1) I don't want to have to deal with situations where the user doesn't choose the right formatting for that cell or column (I'd have to code something pretty complicated to check and fix the formatting of all the cells), and 2) I want to make sure that zip codes and phone numbers don't get their leading zeros chopped off.